# Не скачивается до конца файл с сервера

Tags: php

При помощи скрипта скачивается файл, но он не скачивается до конца, а в папке загрузки имеем:
165418_19A998F4-5E7D-4ECC-920F-624137994A77.jpeg.crdownload

За отдачу файла отвечает скрипт на PHP:

```html
<?php
require('conf.php');

if(empty($_GET['id'])) {die('Неверный запрос');} //проверим есть ли параметр с именем файла
else {
    $filearr = explode('-', $_GET['id']);
    if ($filearr[1]=="0001"){
        if(empty($filearr[2])) {die('Файл не найден');}
        else {
            $filedata = $connect2->query(<Запрос>);
            if($filedata->num_rows==0){die('Неверный идентификатор');}
            else {
                $row = $filedata->fetch_assoc();
                $file = "/home/data/".$row['filepath']; //полный путь к нашему файлу 
                if(!file_exists($file)) die('Файл не найден'); //проверим существует ли файл
                //Заголовки ответа на запрос, что отвечаем мы потоком байт
                header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
                header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
                header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='.basename($file));
                header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
                header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($file));
                //Передаем наш файл в ответ на запрос
                readfile($file);
                exit();
            }
        }   
    } else {
        die('Неверный запрос');
    }
}
```

В чем может быть дело?

Comment: Как именно проявляется «не скачивается», что пишет браузер при этом?

Comment: У браузера загрузка висит как незавершенная.
А файл скачанный отображается вот так 145217_1500х2152px_25марта.jpg.crdownload

Comment: Может, она и правда незавершённая? Сколько вы пробовали ждать? Какой прогресс скачивания показывается?

Comment: Как я понимаю это значит что файл не до конца скачан с сервера, то есть процесс загрузки файла зависает в самом конце.

Comment: Я раз 100 пробовал скачивать на разных файлах. Размер порядка 1Мб. Одно и тоже повторяется.

Comment: В консоли браузера без ошибок.

Comment: в консоли ошибок сервера тоже пусто(

Comment: Проверяйте вывод (stdout) при исполнении скрипта, вполне могут быть дополнительные данные выведены в поток выдачи, что в итоге скажется на несоответствии размера файла в Content-Length, и фактически отданных данных.

Comment: readfile читает файл и записывает в буфер вывода, не может быть так, что php-скрипт попросту не успевает и убивается по таймауту (обрывается)?

Comment: @Дмитрий на маленьких jpeg-файлах сомнительно

Comment: @Дмитрий у меня аналогичный скрипт работает в других проектах и там все ок даже с файлами на 100Мб